Uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\exp(-nz)}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}$
Consider $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\exp(-nz)}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}},$$ on $D=\{z  \in \mathbb{C} \mid \operatorname{Re}(z)>0\}$.
For each $z \in D$; the series converges absolutely by root test as $|\exp(-z)|=\exp(-\operatorname{Re}(z))<1$; however that convergence is not uniform because $$\lim_{z \to 0^{+}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\exp(-nz)}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}$$ that diverges by comparison test with the harmonic series. Is this a sufficient justification?

I see the exact opposite: if $z\in D$ then $\exp\left(-\operatorname{Re}(z)\right) > 1$ and the series always diverge.

Sorry, I had written the wrong inequality

sort of - I would say that a better argument is to find $x_n \to 0$ with $|S_n(x_n)-f(x_n)| \ge \delta>0$ which would be impossible under uniform continuity (which implies that for all $\epsilon$ there is $n(\epsilon)$ st $|S_n((z)-f(z)| \le \epsilon, n \ge n(\epsilon)$) for all $\Re z >0$; for example choosing $x_n$ st $\exp(-2n x_n) \ge 1$ so $f(x_n)-S_n(x_n) \ge \sum_{n < k \le 2n}  \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}} \ge  \frac{n}{\sqrt{2n(2n+1)}} \ge 1/3$ will do

Another way is to use Cauchy's criterion for uniform convergence, and show it fails. Since the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}$ diverges, there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that for any $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ there are $m>n\geq n_0$ such that $\sum\limits_{k=n}^m \frac{1}{\sqrt{k(k+1)}}\geq\epsilon$.
So now take this specific $\epsilon$. For any $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ take $m>n\geq n_0$ as above and take $z=\frac{1}{m}$. Then:
$|\sum\limits_{k=n}^m\frac{e^{-kz}}{\sqrt{k(k+1)}}|=\sum\limits_{k=n}^m\frac{e^{-\frac{k}{m}}}{\sqrt{k(k+1)}}\geq\sum\limits_{k=n}^m\frac{e^{-1}}{\sqrt{k(k+1)}}\geq e^{-1}\epsilon$
And so the Cauchy criterion for uniform convergence fails.

Your  justification is sufficient. Actually, we have the following result:


Suppose $z_0$ is a limit point of $E\subset\mathbb C$, the series
$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}u_n(z)$
is uniformly convergent on $E$ and $\lim\limits_{E\ni z\to z_0}u_n(z)=a_n$,
then :
(1) $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is convergent;
(2) $$\lim_{E\ni z\to z_0}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} u_n(z)
 =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n.$$


Proof: (1) Given any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb N$, such that when $m,n>N$, we have
$$|u_m(z)+\cdots+u_n(z)|<\epsilon,\quad \forall z\in E.$$
Let $E\ni z\to z_0$, we hvae
$$|a_m+\cdots+a_n|\leq\epsilon,$$
this implies series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is convergent.
(2) Given any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb N$, such that
$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} u_n(z)-\sum_{k=1}^{N} u_k(z)\right|<\frac{\epsilon}3,\quad \forall z\in E,$$
and
$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n-\sum_{k=1}^{N} a_k\right|<\frac{\epsilon}3.$$
Due to $\lim\limits_{E\ni z\to z_0}u_n(z)=a_n$, we know
$$\lim_{E\ni z\to z_0}\sum_{k=1}^{N}u_k(z)-\sum_{k=1}^{N}a_n,$$
then there exists $\delta>0$, such that, when $z\in E$ and $0<|z-z_0|<\delta$, we have
$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^{N}u_k(z)-\sum_{k=1}^{N}a_n\right|<\frac{\epsilon}3.$$
So when $z\in E$ and $0<|z-z_0|<\delta$, we get
$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} u_n(z)
 -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n\right|
\leq\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} u_n(z)-\sum_{k=1}^{N} u_k(z)\right|+\left|\sum_{k=1}^{N} u_k(z)-\sum_{k=1}^{N} a_k\right|+\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n-\sum_{k=1}^{N} a_k\right|$$
$$<\frac{\epsilon}3+\frac{\epsilon}3+\frac{\epsilon}3=\epsilon.$$


For the OP's question:
$$\lim_{z\to0+}\frac{\exp(-nz)}{\sqrt{(n(n+1))}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n(n+1))}},\quad \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n(n+1))}}=+\infty,$$
by the result $(1)$, we know $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\exp(-nz)}{\sqrt{(n(n+1))}}$$
is not uniformly convergent on $\{\Re(z)>0\}$.


